# ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials exception trying to call Google Vision API

Tags: java, maven, google-vision

I'm trying to evaluate Google vision endpoint. my pom is configured like below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
  <version>1.69.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There are no other google dependency added. I see below conflict within the vision dependency itself.
[image]

When I run the code I'm getting below error.

```
GoogleAuthLibraryCallCredentials#createJwtHelperOrNull#229 - Failed to create JWT helper. This is unexpected
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.security.PrivateKey, java.lang.String)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
```

I believe this has something to do with mismatched versions. but got no idea which one to use and how to fix dependency issues within the same jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug introduced in recent versions of the SDK. It affects several Google Cloud Java SDK. I encountered a similar issue with the *pubsub* client. As a workaround, using version *1.67.0* should make your code working.

Here is a bug report I opened:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/4946

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used 1.66 and it worked. will try 1.67 as well.